# Given a binary matrix of 0 and 1. Find the longest sequence of 1's either row wise or column wise. JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a binary matrix of 0 and 1. Find the longest sequence of 1's either row wise or column wise.

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
```

It should return highest count – 3. Help please write this program on Java. I wrote a simple algorithm, but it does not take into account the sequence.

```
public int columnMaxSequence(int[][] matrix) {

    int maxSequence = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (matrix[j][i] == 1) {
                max++;
            }
        }
        if (max > maxSequence) {
            maxSequence = max;
        }
        max = 0;
    }
    return maxSequence;
}

public int rowMaxSequence(int[][] matrix) {

    int maxSequence = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                max++;
            }
        }
        if (max > maxSequence) {
            maxSequence = max;
        }
        max = 0;
    }
    return maxSequence;
}

/*
 Returns the maximum sequence of 1s in a matrix.
 */
public int maxSequence(int[][] matrix) {

    int rowMaxSequence = rowMaxSequence(matrix);
    int columnMaxSequence = columnMaxSequence(matrix);

    if (rowMaxSequence >= columnMaxSequence) {
        return rowMaxSequence;
    } else {
        return columnMaxSequence;
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample input you have provided isn't a matrix in any form, as it should contain 1, 4, 9, 16 etc elements. Please provide a sample input and your desired output alongside.

Comment: I've newly edited my answer, the previous code wouldn't have worked. Please check the latest version.

Comment: I've edited the comment again, because I previously assumed the matrix would be a square.

Comment: @RoboMop it is my fault, sorry. This is my first question on stack overflow and I did not fully understand all the nuances of this site. Many thanks for the quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this out:

```
void main(int[][] matrix)
{
    System.out.println(Math.max(columnMaxSequence(matrix), rowMaxSequence(matrix)));
}

public int columnMaxSequence(int[][] matrix)
{
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) // Column Index
    {
        int tempMax = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) // Row Index
        {
            if(matrix[j][i] == 1)
            {
                tempMax = 1;
                for(int k = j+1; k < matrix.length; k++)
                {
                    if(matrix[k][i] == 1)
                        tempMax++;
                    else break;
                }
                if(max < tempMax)
                    max = tempMax;
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

public int rowMaxSequence(int[][] matrix)
{
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        int tempMax = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                tempMax = 1;
                for(int k = j+1; k < matrix[0].length; k++)
                {
                    if(matrix[i][k] == 1)
                        tempMax++;
                    else break;
                }
                if(max < tempMax)
                    max = tempMax;
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

## Explanation -

**For rowMaxSequence()**:

The loop goes down the matrix, and `i` stores the value of each row's index. `j` stores the index of each element in row `i`. At `(i, j)` if the matrix finds a 1, then it counts the number of 1's in that row until it finds a 0 - then it breaks. It keeps checking that row in the same manner, and when the orw is complete, it goes down to the next row.

**For columnMaxSequence()**:

The loop goes across the matrix to the right, and `i` is the current column's index. `j` is the element in that column. If `(j, i)` is a 1, then it counts the 1's below it, until a 0 is found. Then it breaks. It keeps checking the column in this manner, and moves on to the right column.

Comment: You should check the above code again. It produces wrong result for some cases. Take for example the test case  `int[][] matrix = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0} };` Instead of 3 your code prints 1.

Comment: @Eritrean I've got the problem, I just assumed the rows and columns were of the same size